# Perl5.12 not installing via Macports

Tags: macports

When trying to install Imagemagick via Macports, I keep getting an error when it goes to build the perl5.12 dependancy. It says: `Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.`

I’ve tried updating Macports, installing/building perl5.12 independently, uninstalling and reinstalling perl5.12 to no avail. Here’s what error part of the log says:

```
Making x2p stuff
:info:build ./perl -f -Ilib pod/buildtoc --build-toc -q
:info:build make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_perl5.12/perl5.12/work/perl-5.12.3/x2p'
:info:build You haven't done a "make depend" yet!
:info:build make[1]: *** [hash.o] Error 1
:info:build make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_perl5.12/perl5.12/work/perl-5.12.3/x2p'
:info:build make: *** [translators] Error 2
:info:build make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
:info:build make: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_perl5.12/perl5.12/work/perl-5.12.3'
:info:build shell command " cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_perl5.12/perl5.12/work/perl-5.12.3" && /usr/bin/make -j2 -w all " returned error 2
:error:build Target org.macports.build returned: shell command failed (see log for details)
:debug:build Backtrace: shell command failed (see log for details)
    while executing
"command_exec build"
    (procedure "portbuild::build_main" line 8)
    invoked from within
"$procedure $targetname"
:info:build Warning: the following items did not execute (for perl5.12): org.macports.activate org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
:error:build Failed to install perl5.12
:debug:build couldn't open "/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/tclIndex": no such file or directory
    while executing
"open [file join $dir tclIndex]"
:notice:build Log for perl5.12 is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_perl5.12/perl5.12/main.log
```

[Here’s the whole log.](http://z17.me/1Dfm+)

Does anybody know what’s going on or what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: You cut off the relevant part of the log; the interesting error messages from the build system would have been above that first line.

Comment: @Raim Yeah, sorry about that. Added now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that latest macPorts update fixed my issue, just had to run selfupdate.

Answer (score -3):

What version of Mac OS X do you have? I have Lion, and it comes with Perl 5.12.3. You may need to install the developer tools.

You can always try [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads) which is version 5.12.4. I haven't tried ActivePerl on the Mac, but if you have the developer tools installed, you'll have the required gcc compiler and make installed, so you can install the XS CPAN packages.

On the PC, you have to install CPAN from the Perl Package Manager and not all CPAN modules will install, but I don't know if you have the same issues with ActivePerl on the Mac since the Mac is a Unix operating system.